# How to stop XmlSerializer from adding newlines to blank elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am serializing an object like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());            
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

(having created the nodes like this)

```
XmlElement newchild = doc.CreateElement(nodename);
newchild.InnerText = data;
targetnode.AppendChild(newchild);
```

if `data!=""` all is well and serializer returns:

`<mynode>TheData</mynode>`

If `data==""` the serializer returns:

```
<mynode>
</mynode>
```

Where did that blank line come from?

I've tried the obvious like only setting `newchild.InnerText=data` when data is nonblank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple route

            `if (data.Length == 0) newchild.IsEmpty = true;
            else newchild.InnerText = data;`

hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you are using an xml document why didn't you just use on of the Write methods on the document itself?

Comment: Good question. I may have to slap myself.

Answer (score 1):

In XML both `<mynode><\mynode>` and `<mynode>\n</mynode>` are equivalent, so it should not matter, but you could modify the underlining [XMLWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) to Serialize the output the way you want it.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not equivalent to the client app parsing my XML (over which I have no control).  How would I modify the XMLWriter ?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: 3.5, but I think I've found a different route.